# SQL Index on foreign key

Tags: mysql, sql

When I join 2 tables `tbl1`, `tbl2` on `column1`, where `column1` is primary key on `tbl1`. Assuming that `column1` is not automatically indexed should I create an index on both `tbl1.column1` and `tbl2.column1` or just on `tbl2.column1`. Are the number of rows of each table affect that choice?

Comment: Product specific question. Which dbms are you using?

Comment: I am using mysql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A primary key *is* automatically indexed.  There is no way around that (this is how the "unique" part of the unique constraint is implemented).  So, `tbl1.column1` has an index.  No other index is needed.

As for `tbl2.column2`, you should probably have an index on that.  MySQL does create an index if you explicitly declare a foreign key relationship.  So, with the explicit declaration, no other index is necessary.  Note:  this is not true of all databases.

The presence of indexes does not change the results of queries nor the number of rows in the table, so I don't understand your final question.  Indexes implement relational integrity and improve (hopefully!) performance on certain types of queries

Comment: In my final question I mean if the number of rows affect my choice on which index shooulld I create.

Comment: @JohnOlow . . . If one of the tables is really small (the data fits on a single data page), then an index may not give much performance.

Answer (score 0):

Generally yes, because often you'll want to do the reverse of the join at some point.